# How to run a function if an onchange is true

Tags: javascript, html, function, onchange

I want to ask how would you put in code, if a specific Onchange() event has occurred then run a specific function in another onchange event?

So if onchange occurs (lets call this changeoperation then it will run either function1 or function2 depending on 
 if another onchange event has occurred before(lets call this changediv), if changediv has occured and then onchange (changeoperation) has occurred then run function1 in changeoperation otherwise run function2.

Might be confusing and I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

```
var hasChanged = false;

element1.onchange = function() {
    hasChanged = true;
}

element2.onchange = function() {
    if (hasChanged) {
        // the user changed the first element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the onchange property of the element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
 <html>
   <head>
     <title> Bla! </title>
     <script type='text/javascript'>
        function onchange1(obj) {
            obj.onchange = function () {onchange2(this);};
            alert ("onchange 1 fired!");
        }
        function onchange2(obj) {
            obj.onchange = null;
            alert ("onchange 2 fired!");
        }
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <input type='text' onchange='onchange1(this);'>
   </body>
 </html>
```